# app wise after_action in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

So, I'm keeping track of every email I send to my user.

I can add `after_action :add_email_sent` to every mailer file but it's not very DRY.

I'm more looking for a way to have an app wise after_action callback that will be triggered whenever an email is sent.

Comment: Create a custom mailer class and make all mailers inherit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `ApplicationMailer` class which inherits from `ActionMailer::Base` and add `after_action` to it. Then inherit all mailers from `ApplicationMailer`.